# SQL select last 10 rows in ascending order

Tags: php, sql

here's my current code:

```
$messages = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `user`, `message` FROM `chat` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($messages)) {
    echo "<strong>".$row['user'].":</strong> ".safe_out($row['message'])."<br />";  
}
```

This prints the last 10 messages from the `chat` table in descending order. What I'm trying to do is print the last 10 messages in ascending order.

Changing `DESC` to `ASC` just prints out the first 10 messages, but I'm trying to get the last 10 messages to print in ascending order.

Do I need to put the mysqli_query results into an array and use `reverse` or is there an easier way?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a derived table to re-sort the last 10 messages in ascending order

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT `id`, `user`, `message` FROM `chat` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10
) t1 ORDER BY t1.id
```

Comment: How about in SQL Server?